# reactive to mouse colourful fluid background for website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've found code to make a fluid colorful background for my website but the problem it that it isn't colorful enough.
most of it white. the colorful part stays on the edges. The center stays white. Help me make it more colorful.

```
code- https://codepen.io/assassin9099/pen/VwNpVdx
```

please enlarge the viewer as much as you can to see the issue
i'm hoping for something like the https://advanced.team/ website

Comment: I have no experience with OpenGL shaders, but after a bit of meddling I think you should toy with the RGB color multiplification factors in lines 602, 609, 649 and 663 in your JS. The lower the mult result, the darker your colors. Right now, on each of those lines the random base RGB values are multiplied with equal values, try to vary those.